# Citations never italicized

Tags: citing, theorems, italic

I have some citations which appear inside a theorem like

```
\begin{thm}[The Strong Perfect Graph Theorem]\cite[Theorem 8.3]{Cha-Les-Zha11} A graph 
$G$ is perfect if and only if neither $G$ nor $\bar{G}$ contains an induced odd cycle
of length 5 or more.
\end{thm}
```

where thm is defined by

```
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
```

This citation appears in italics in the PDF.  But, if I were to do the exact same citation outside of a theorem, it would not appear in italics.  Is there a way to force it to always be plain (not italicized)?

Comment: As far as I know, the environment `thm` is not standard in LaTeX. Did you use a package or did you define this environment in your preamble?

Comment: @Vivi True, sorry.  I added an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the citation in a `\textup`, like

```
\textup{\cite[Theorem 8.3]{Cha-Les-Zha11}}
```