# Normal text for \cite, \ref in all theorem environments

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, theorems

I am working with several theorem environments defined by me, for example

```
\newtheorem{Th}{Теорема}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Tv}[Th]{Твърдение}
```

(the words are in Bulgarian, but it doesn't matter).
In all these theorems and the proof environments I need to use both \cite and \ref.

> What I want is an uniform rule that makes everything in \cite or \ref with normal text in all theorem environments. I don't want to use \textup or similar every time.

I am well aware of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179571/citation-square-brackets-upright-in-theorems) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87803/citations-never-italicized?rq=1) posts but they don't resolve this issue globally.

Here is a working example that would work for me if resolved.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,eucal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
linkcolor={blue!90!black},
citecolor={blue!60!black},
urlcolor={blue!90!black}
}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{Tv}[Th]{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\begin{Th}\label{myProp}
The equation 
\begin{equation}\label{myEq}
x^2y+e^z-\sin{t} = 0.
\end{equation}
has a solution.
\end{Th}

\begin{Th}\cite{X}
The solutions for the equation defined in Proposition \ref{myProp} are
\[
\ldots
\]
\end{Th}



\begin{thebibliography}{999}\itemsep=-.2pc
\bibitem{X} Author X. Paper Y. Year Z.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  what theorem environment are you using?  you don't show one here, so it is probably defined in the document class, which you don't show either.  we need that information to derermine where changes would need to be made.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hello and thank you. My the package behind my document class is given to me by my scientific adviser and were asked not to share its code. However, the basic class that the package uses is {\it report }. I don't know what you mean by what theorem environment I use? You mean a concrete example in the text like \begin{theorem} The Scientst X showed in \cite{...} that ... \end{theorem} ?

Comment: this may do it; not tested:  `\makeatletter \def\@cite#1#2{\textup{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}])} \makeatother`  (sorry for the mashed-together code.  i don't like to post answers unless i'm sure the code works.)  this modifies code from `latex.ltx`.  if it works, i'll look up the definition of `\ref`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked with \cite. By the way, you skipped one }, so the working form is : \makeatletter \def\@cite#1#2{\textup{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}])}} \makeatother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package available called *upref*, which is part of the AMS Classes distribution.

Comment: Adding \usepackage{upref} to the preumble solved the problem with the \ref in the theorem environments. I am also interested to see the solution with the redefinition of \ref without adding packages despite the fact that since *upref* is in the AMS Classes distribution it probably won't create future problems.

Answer (score 4):

since the underlying class file is `report`, and no theorem or bibliography
packages are loaded, the place to look for definitions of `\cite` and `\ref`
are in `report.cls`.  as it happens, neither of those commands is defined
there, so the next place to look is in `latex.ltx`, which
underlies *all* of latex.

the definition for `\cite` is fairly complicated, and the relevant part is
not in the "main" definition.  looking for a "related" definition that
contains the brackets and actually sets something, one finds `\@cite`,
which can easily be "repaired" by adding `\textup{...}` around the part
that prints:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{\textup{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}}
\makeatother
```

`\ref` is not done the same way, and this is not tested (i will do so later):

```
\makeatletter
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
    \@firstoftwo{\textup{#1}}}
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@secondoftwo{\textup{#1}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The command for \cite worked for me, but the command about \ref didn't.

Comment: okay.  i will have to create a test, but i haven't time right now.  (that's why on this site we ask for compilable examples; then we can start with something we can cut and paste.)

Comment: I made a working example that probably would work for me, see edit of the original post.

Comment: Actually the in the code about \cite there is one redundant ")" symbol which produces citations like "[37])". The correct one is \makeatletter \def\@cite#1#2{\textup{[{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}]}} \makeatother

Comment: @Veliko -- thanks.  (if you edit in a correction like this, where the code is clearly wrong, i would certainly accept it.)  fixed.